# Architecture-independent "pure logic" code generation

Tags: code-generation

I don't really know if any common terms exist for what I'm asking about, so I apologize for possible stupid misuse of the terms.

I'm interested, if there are any solutions or at least experiments for creating "pure logic" code, abstract of any architectural patterns, and later generation of architecture-specific code based on it.

For example:

"pure logic" is addition of two integers — a and b

it can be dumped as inline "= a + b"

or as a function "function sum(a,b){return a+b}; =sum(a,b)"

or as a class "class Sum(a, b){...}; s = new Sum(a,b); =s.result();

or maybe this class has no constructor arguments but requires applying them after construction

or it accepts a dictionary with dozen possible keys including 2 we need

or maybe we have DI/IoC container and we call lazy-loaded singleton serevice with 2 injected arguments

and so on

So, basically, it's like we have a mix of global functions and variables, and then we apply generation rules and templates to get a specific coder-friendly result.

Comment: The requirements here aren't really very clear...

Comment: If you believe that "a+b" is architecture independent, try adding 2^32-1 and 1 on your favorite 32 bit architecture.  You won't get an architecture independent answer.   The point of this is that when you generate code at any level of abstraction, you have to define the semantics *precisely* at level of abstraction.  When you generate code for a real architecture, you have to take into account the difference in semantics from the abstract semantics and the target architecture semantics.  *Sometimes* you can use what looks like the same operator (e.g., if you can prove both operands are small).

Comment: @IraBaxter 
What I'm looking for is not some magic AI, but merely text dumper designed specifically for code-generation. So if "a+b" is not supposed to work for certain architecture it can be configured to dump in another way.

Comment: You can't say "architecture independent" and "not supposed to work for a certain architecture" reasonably in the same breath.  "The requirements here aren't really very clear."

Comment: @IraBaxter Please don't be picky about terms — I mentioned that I don't know how exactly it should be called. You can call it "less dependent" or whatever you want. 
For example, let's take a look at haxe. It compiles into multiple languages and can be considered language-independent, however each target may require a bit of tuning to work. That is enough of "independency" for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot escape having to define some syntax, and giving it semantics. And that gives you a language. In this language you have types (integers) and an operation (you can add them).

So now this business of generating code is basically your compiler for the language, which uses various high level languages as the back end.

Since some of the languages are perhaps not as "pure" as your high level language, or are semantically distant in various ways, the generated code in some of the back-end dialects might end up looking like dog's breakfast in order to precisely implement the semantics.

Comment: ... or the generated code handles edge cases in the original language badly (e.g., "pray there's no overflow").